# Extremely High Hard Disk Reading Usage

Tags: centos, hard-drive, wordpress, io

My `VPS` configuration is as follows:

- H.D.D = 25GB
- RAM = 256MB
- OS : CentOS 5.5

I received an email from server provider showing that my VPS H.D.D read usage is 137GB in one day. I have installed Kloxo as a Control Panel and APF for firewall. The one website is on my server that based on WordPress.

Could any one please explain this extremely use ? Or guide me to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by installing Munin and graphing the I/O activity and memory utilisation. You'll quickly see if you're eating into SWAP.

`iotop` is a great application that can show you HDD utilisation by process and will give you a graphical representation as to what process is eating up your HDD resources.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you run low on RAM and it's using a lot's of swap which is on HDD.

Comment: Bingo. That's the most likely answer.

Comment: You can fix it by switching PHP to fast-cgi mode and running just one fast-cgi process. However this depends on your configuration, e.g. what folder are you using etc.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are you need more memory.  If the MySQL server for wordpress is installed on the same machine you are starving the MySQL database for memory.